# Infinite loop in runnable goes out?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, queue, runnable

Some simplified code to illustrate my problem:

```
public class QueriesQueueRunnable implements Runnable {

    private List<String> queue = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            if (!this.getQueue().isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(this.getQueue().get(0));
                    this.getQueue().remove(0);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
QueriesQueueRunnable queriesQueueRunnable = new QueriesQueueRunnable();
Thread thread = new Thread(queriesQueueRunnable).start();




for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     if(i==500){
         try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);                 
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
     }
    queriesQueueRunnable.getQueue().add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

The output is only showing until the i==499 iteration. Why? It's like the execution goes out of the runnable loop.

Java 1.7

Comment: Have you waited the full five seconds? Are there any error messages, or it just hangs?

Comment: `Thread thread = new Thread(queriesQueueRunnable).start();` is a compile error.

Comment: I have waited the five seconds yes. There are not any error. The output just stops in the 499.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your code is `sleep`ing, the other thread is spinning endlessly and fruitlessly, leaving it vulnerable to optimization by the JIT compiler. Since that thread has no way of knowing that `queue` is being updated, the optimizer assumes that `queue.isEmpty()` will forever return `true` and skips the check entirely.

One way to avoid this problem is to make the `queue` field `volatile`, which informs the JVM that others threads can be modifying the value concurrently:

```
private volatile List<String> queue = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Note that although this will solve your particular problem, your code is still far from thread-safe because `ArrayList` is not mean for concurrent access.

Also note that your program will never complete, unless you make the secondary thread a [daemon thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)).

Comment: Then should I use Vector and synchronized to make my code thread-safe?

Comment: @user2132478 If you use synchronization you don't need a Vector, but if you use a Vector you'll still need synchronization around your if-then logic. But you're probably better off with a concurrent queue from the [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.